# heroku deployment with play framework 1.2.4 with own secure module

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a play framework application (v1.2.4) to deploy to heroku.

I added secure module to my play app by copying the secure module from local PLAY_HOME. So that I could change Secure code to suit my project's needs.

Thus my folder structure looks like

- work-root/

  - /play-project/ -> contains all play, libs & conf/application.conf
  - /secure/ -> copy of local secure module (& modified, which is why I copied. )

At the work-root, I did the following git operations:

```
git init
git add. 
git commit -m 'first commmit with customised secure'
```

**Please not that I didn't just commit from the play app folder (in play-project) but from a level above so that the custom secure app is also committed.**

Then I created heroku app by 
    heroku create -s cedar --buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-pl

Which all worked.

to push code & have it deployed in heroku I did 
     git push heroku master

This didn't work, 
    ~ Oops. conf/routes or conf/application.conf missing.

This is because they are not there but a level below.
I want to be able to tell Heroku that this is a play app the application.conf is in a "folder" called [play-project] & is within the current working directory.

Can someone please help me?
Many thanks Kind regards

--Rana Das

Answer (score 3):

The default Play buildpack looks for those files.  You can either fork the buildpack to make it work for your needs or you can switch to a more standard structure.  To do what you want just go with a standard Play project layout (with the Play app in the root dir).  Then for the secure module simply copy it's source into the `modules/secure` directory.  Then Play will use your version of the module.

Comment: I'll take the second option. I don't think I was achieving anything special having two different folders anyway. Thanks a million James, always so helpful. regards --Rana

Comment: This works great for me but the only problem is that when I run $ play dependencies --sync, my modules are deleted. Any way around this?